# Unit Test using the DomainClassConverter feature of Spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

I'm trying to code a unit test for a method defined in a controller.
The method is like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/products")
public class RestProductController {

 @RequestMapping(value="/{product}/skus", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<SkuSummaryVO> getSkuByProduct(@Valid @PathVariable Product product){
        List<SkuSummaryVO> skusByProductVOs = skuService.getSkusByProduct(product);
        return skusByProductVOs;
    }
}
```

We use in our Configuration class the annotation @EnableSpringDataWebSupport to enable the DomainClassConverter feature. So we can use the JPA entity as a @PathVariable. So when a product id will be set in the URL, we will get the product (with a request behind the scene).

We are developing unit test without enabling the Spring App Context and using Mockito.
So we initialize the mockMvcBuilders like this:

```
public class RestProductControllerTest {

    ...

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        RestProductController restProductController = new RestProductController();
        ...
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(restProductController).build();
    }
}
```

and the test method is like this:

```
    @Test
    public void testGetProductById() throws Exception {
        ...
        String jsonResult = ...;     
        mockMvc.perform(get("/products/123/skus").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(content().string(jsonResult));
    }
```

And I get a 500 for the HttpCode (the status)

And the unit tests work fine for the controller methods witch are not using the DomainClassConverter feature (for example if I use a `Long productId` instead of a `Product product` as a parameter of  `getSkuByProduct`, it will work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**: on second thought, what I originally proposed below could never work since `DomainClassConverter` requires that your Spring Data Repositories be present in the `ApplicationContext`, and in your example you are using `StandaloneMockMvcBuilder` which will never create an `ApplicationContext` that contains your Spring Data Repositories.

The way I see it, you have two options.

1. Convert your test to an integration test using a real `ApplicationContext` (loaded via `@ContextConfiguration` as demonstrated in the reference manual) and pass that to `MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(WebApplicationContext)`. If the configured `ApplicationContext` includes your Spring Data web configuration, you should be good to go.
2. Forgo the use of `DomainClassConverter` in your unit test, and instead set a custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` (e.g., a stub or a mock) via `StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.setCustomArgumentResolvers(HandlerMethodArgumentResolver...)`. Your custom resolver could then return whatever `Product` instance you desire.

---

You'll have to register an instance of the `DomainClassConverter` with the `ConversionService` in the `StandaloneMockMvcBuilder` that is created when you invoke `MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(Object...)`.

In `SpringDataWebConfiguration.registerDomainClassConverterFor()`, you can see that the `DomainClassConverter` is instantiated (and indirectly registered) like this:

```
DomainClassConverter<FormattingConversionService> converter =
    new DomainClassConverter<FormattingConversionService>(conversionService);
converter.setApplicationContext(context);
```

And you can set your own `FormattingConversionService` via `StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.setConversionService()`. See `WebMvcConfigurationSupport.mvcConversionService()` for an example of how to configure the `ConversionService` for a web environment.

The challenge then is how to obtain a reference to the `ApplicationContext`. Internally, `StandaloneMockMvcBuilder` uses a `StubWebApplicationContext`, but as far as I can see (prior to Spring 4.1) there is no way to access it directly without subclassing `StandaloneMockMvcBuilder`.

As of Spring Framework 4.1, you could implement a custom `MockMvcConfigurer` (which gives you access to the `WebApplicationContext` via its `beforeMockMvcCreated()` method.

So hopefully that's enough information to get you on the right track!

Good luck...

Sam

Comment: We changed the code and we dont use DomainClassConverter anymore.we have a relation `@ManyToOne` to `Product` from the `Sku` entity and we just found that in Spring data JPA we can access to the product just with the id (not with the full product entity so no more `DomainClassConverter`) using special keywords for the method name: `findByProductId` in our repository interface (witch extends JpaRepository).With the 'DomainClassConverter' the method used was `findByProduct` In the doc of Spring data they talk about the method keywords name but itsnot clear when we have relation between entities.

Comment: But otherwise we would go to your method 1. But thanks for your clear answer.

Comment: You're very welcome. And I'm glad you found a cleaner solution with the `findByProductId()` approach!

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the string to entity conversion through `WebConversionService`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58169405/1833705) answer for some code example and more details.

Comment: Alternatively you can use spy to override only selected method calls. This caused less issues in my setup. An example is in my blog post: https://www.kobelnet.ch/2020/08/16/workaround-for-missing-domainclassconverter-in-spring-boot-junit-tests